# How would I show that there is no holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $C\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\exp f(z) = z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not sure how to show it's not holomorphic. I can find a general equation for $f(z)$ but can only seem to show it's not one to one, and am not sure how to show it is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ then integrating $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{dz}$ along any contour in the domain - in particular, a contour going once around the origin - gets you back to where you started, *i.e.* the integral is zero. But by the chain rule $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{dz} = 1/z$, and integrating $1/z$ along such a contour gets a residue of $2\pi i$. This contradicts the existence of such an $f$.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by a contour? I'm struggling to visualise the function f(z), I think it would be equal to the Log( modz) + iarg(z)+ 2(pi)n(i) but am struggling to visualise this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the function - or rather, the multi-function. If you cut out a lot of discs of paper, slice them all along a radius, and glue them together radius to radius then you can make a surface on which you can draw the log function continuously. You can't do it on a flat plane.

A contour is a closed non-self-intersecting curve on the complex plane -- they feature a lot in first-semester complex analysis. The unit circle would work for this argument..

Comment: You should say "closed contour"